# Why are Kan extensions useful?

Tags: category-theory

I'm a Ph.D. student in algebraic geometry dealing mostly with D-modules and perverse sheaves. As such, I'm extensively aware of the power and beauty of the usual categorical constructions (limits, colimits, adjunctions, universal properties, ...).

I feel that I understand pretty well the definition of Kan extensions and why they're related to all the other constructions cited above, but I don't know a single example (which is not a derived functor) which becomes "clearer" in this setting.

In other words, if I only knew the other categorical constructions *and* derived functors, I feel that I wouldn't lose anything.

Can someone please convince me otherwise?

Comment: As a category theorist I am inclined to agree that Kan extensions in general do not seem to be as important as their various special cases. The Kan extension functor, i.e. the left/right adjoints of the precomposition functor, shows up often enough that it is convenient to have a name for it, though.

Comment: I find things as (co)induction (e.g. of $G$-representations) to make much more sense when viewed as Kan extensions. Another example is Day convolution. Another is weighted (co)limits.

Comment: Dear @АрсенийКряжев, would you mind explaining why? I'm not very used to coinduction of $G$-representations, but coextension of scalars for modules seems somewhat natural for me, given that it is right adjoint to restriction of scalars.

Comment: @Gabriel For one thing, some manipulations with them depend only on the fact that they are adjoints to restriction. For another, more specific to them being Kan extensions, the formulas for them are (to me) much easier to remember/understand with such a perspective. It might be just me.

Comment: @АрсенийКряжев, I unfortunately don't how somes formulas (which ones?) become simpler with such a perspective but I would love to understand more. I would appreciate a lot if you could present some example or explanation :)

Comment: See e.g. example 6.2.8 in Category Theory in Context.